# Is there exception to rule that if address can be find out using & it's lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-address, lvalue, rvalue

Is there any exception to rule that if I can find address using & it's l-value otherwise r-value?

For example,

```
int i;
```

`&i` will give address of i, but I cannot take address of `(i + 5)`, unless I is pointer or array.

Regards

Comment: Please suggest reason of downvoting.

Comment: `i+5` doesn't have an address, it's an expression. `&` is here for finding addresses of memory locations.

Comment: @user35443 So that is what I said, it is r value? Please read question carefully.

Comment: `operator&` can be overloaded. E.g. `struct foo { void operator&(); };`, then you can even `&foo{}`.

Comment: `Foo::bar` isn't an lvalue, but you can use `&` on it to get a pointer to that member, if that counts.

Comment: @chris Doesn't [expr.prim.general]p10 say it's an lvalue?

Comment: @dyp, Ah, I was looking at [expr.unary.op]/3 and figured that if it differentiated this from lvalue, it probably isn't an lvalue. Looking into it, my previous comment was going for a non-static member of a class rather than a static one or something in a namespace. Unfortunately, syntax alone isn't enough for that.

Comment: @PranitKothari _"Please suggest reason of downvoting."_ Wasn't me, but [nope](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question).

Comment: @chris In a class-member-access expression, it's not necessarily an lvalue. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2b7f85b24b5ad62

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's just saying that it should not be compulsory to post a reason; it does not prevent asking for or giving a reason

Comment: @dyp that same section says "The result is an lvalue if the member is a
function or a variable and a prvalue otherwise."  I'm having trouble thinking of examples for the "otherwise" here (and [expr.unary.op]/3 appears to assume there is no "otherwise"!)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Enumerators are the only exception AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious exception is overloading the prefix `&` operator for your own type:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X* operator&()
    {
        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << &X() << '\n';
}
```

This prints the address of the temporary object, which happens to be `0x7fff76012d9f` when I ran it.